# how can i import register button in auth laravel

Tags: laravel

How can I import register in `auth`? Just like below:

laravel use the login and registration page just like this :

```
   @if (Auth::guest())
          <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>
          <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a></li>

    @else{
          <li><a href="{{ url('/logout') }}">Logout</a></li>
    @endif
```

but I want to use the registration button inside auth... like this:

```
   @if (Auth::guest())
          <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>

    @else{
          <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a></li>
          <li><a href="{{ url('/logout') }}">Logout</a></li>
    @endif
```

how can I do this ..

Comment: Your second block of code should word.

Answer (score 1):

Open the view of your Login? probably located `resources/views/auth/login` ?

Comment: If you open that view, you can see that there is an button which you don't want there? i guess deeper than this can't

Answer (score 0):

go to `/resources/view/layouts/app.blade.php`
then remove 58 no line to remove register button